# jquery - if statement on different page loads?

Tags: jquery, pageload

Is there any functions that I can use to check which page(url) was loaded?

I want to perform if statement below...

```
if(http://www.something.com/hey/)
{ 
do something here;
} else { something else}
```

Comment: you may use `if (location=='http://www.something.com/hey/')` but it's rarely a good idea. It would be cleaner to call the right function from the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location.href.

```
if(window.location.href === 'http://www.something.com/hey/') { 
    // Do something here.
} else { 
    // Something else.
}
```